# How to prevent regular users (non admin) from pinning/unpinning shortcuts to the taskbar in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, group-policy

I would like to prevent regular users from pinning/unpinning shortcuts to the taskbar by enforcing a selective GPO that would be bypassed for administrators. Is it possible?

Comment: but why? Taskbar is each user's preferences so they should be allowed to do their own customizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may disallow (un)pinning to the taskbar, but that will
apply to all users including administrators.
An administrator will need to disable
this policy in order to (un)pin tasks.

Here is how :

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar*
- Double-click "Do not allow pinning programs to the Taskbar"
- Select "Enabled"
- Click Apply and then OK.

You may also choose to do the same for the policy
"Do not allow pinning Store app to the Taskbar".

Comment: Thanks! In this situation, is there not any way to selectively enable a rule for a specific set of users only? That looks like a serious Windows limitation to me.

Comment: I don't know of such a specific policy. I suspect Microsoft didn't implement one.